# How do I find .torrent files for completed downloads?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

The hard drive on my desktop recently failed. More fool I, I did not have a coherent backup plan. The shop I bought the computer from migrated my files, including my torrent directory after I assured them it was all legal stuff (which it is. I had all of my Humble Bundle torrents and several public domain items). Problem is, they only copied over the directory with the completed files. Is there a way to go through and search the internet for corresponding torrent files so that I can reshare the ones whose source I've forgotten? I have the file names and the sizes, since they are completed files.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as someone who buys humble bundle games myself, downloading them through a torrent remains illegal. Otherwise, you have them in your steam and they auto-download.

Comment: @LPChip:
You've never noticed the torrent download links off of the bundle pages? These are all ones that I've bought. I keep sharing the torrents so as to reduce the server load for the Humble Bundle people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can use every tool to do legal or illegal things, there's no need to discuss the legality of torrent.

If it's about resharing the files, you can download the torrent file again from it's source. If the file's  destination is the same, it will recognize the files, recheck the file and allow you to seed it.

If you want to look for the origin .torrent files on your old system, the path depends on the client you use.

Comment: True, true regarding the legality question. Unfortunately, far too many people seem to jump toward the illegal side of things, so I always feel obligated to clarify, kind of like the {insert fringe group here} who has to clarify that they're "not one of the crazy ones". :)

I probably will try just plugging the file name in. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with 'humble bundle' but regardless-- if you are looking for torrent files, any file you could search for on say, google.com, search a filename (or topic) you are looking for and add the word 'torrent' in the search. Google tracks pretty much everything...

Example Search: freeware torrent (would find any torrents of freeware that are listed as freeware...)

There really is not another way unless you know of other specific search sites to go to. Be careful though, you may find legality is not where you think it is on this one.

Update: In the op's posting it is indicated in a comment that Humble Bundle may provide torrent links as their method of software distribution to their customers. If that is the case, this is perfectly okay, and it may be required to contact any tech support at Humble Bundle to try to recover any that are lost.

Answer (score 1):

The long and the short is, no.

depending on your client, it may be in your appdata folder (on windows it tends to be *%appdata%/clientname*) but if not, then probably not. There's probably going to be too many varients to tell.